# How can I make image brighter (more light as flash effect) using Core Graphics

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, core-graphics

How can I get flash effect for images got from Camera?
After I got image from camera (it shows in UIImageView) and before saving it as a file I'd like to lighten (in some cases) image by pressing Flash button. Is it possible by using Core Graphics ??

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649035/change-the-state-of-a-customized-button-button-with-an-image/2672370#2672370). That question was about making an image darker, but you could use exactly the same code and make the image lighter by overlaying a partially transparent white color:

```
//draw a 50% white overlay
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(cx, 1.0, 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(cx, imageRect);
```

Comment: You might be able to enhance the visual appearance of this by changing your blend mode. `CGContextSetBlendMode()`. Promising choices: `kCGBlendModeLighten, kCGBlendModeColorDodge, kCGBlendModeColorBurn, kCGBlendModeSoftLight, kCGBlendModeHardLight, kCGBlendModeSaturation, kCGBlendModeLuminosity`

Comment: Did you see that question is tree years old ? Those time was no *BlendMode. It was iPhone OS 3.11